# Can a child class fields be used in parent class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Is there any way to use the child class fields or properties inside parent class constructor or methods?

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {

    }
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    public int y;
    public Child()
    {

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent obj = new Child();
        obj.y = 10;
    }
}
```

In the above code i can't access the field 'y'

Comment: Yes, what exactly do you want? Would you provide an example, please?

Comment: Not without using child class instance, which is a bad idea, base class shouldn't know its derived classes.

Comment: I don't have any examples since it was an question asked to me during a discussion of C# and OOPS concepts

Comment: Just try it out. Shouldn´t be that complicated to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried to code but it shows error while using the field of child class in base class,
that's why i asked is there any possible ways

Comment: _"I tried to code but it shows error while using the field of child class in base class"_ - you should have included that code in your question..

Comment: Just to clarify, when you talk about parent/child classes, you refer to inhertiance like `public class Parent { } public class Child : Parent { }`, right? Or do you mean nested classes like `public class Parent { public class Child { } }`?

Comment: Not nested classes its all about inheritance

Comment: Then no. As @Guy said, the base class shouldn't know its derived classes. You *could* have some kind of virtual Init method which you override in the child class... but even calling virtual methods in the constructor can lead to weird problems if you're not careful.

Comment: Could you help me with a code snippet on how to use those virtual init methods, Please? @Corak

Comment: Maybe you'd like to use (obj as Child).y = 10;

Comment: @ArunGandhi - Ah, I understood "used in parent class" as meaning actually in parent class. Now I see you meant a variable of type of parent class but refering to an instance of child class. So the suggestion of virtual methods doesn't make much sense anymore.

Comment: @Corak I didn't make that changes its done by someone else

Comment: @ArunGandhi - well, that's... weird... because the edit history shows that you put in that code... the other edit seems to just be minor changes in the heading (which made it clearer and easier to understand what the question is about). Does the code that is now in the question represent, what you're trying to do? If not, please do as has already been suggested and edit the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Objects that inherit from Parent do not necessarily have a property y of type int. In fact this would be a violation of Liskov Substitution Principle (the L in SOLID). This principle means that I should be able to assign any object of a type that descends from Parent to that variable and the logic should work. Clearly if I created a class called Child2 which inherited from Parent but did not have a y property, or declared y as some other type (eg DateTime), then your code self evidently couldn't assign the value 10 to that object instance.

There are certain cases where your Parent class could defer to the child class (see virtual and abstract methods and properties for an example). It is possible that the child class to influence the behaviour of one of these virtual or abstract methods by considering the value of y, but the parent can't expose that y without declaring such a property.

Answer (score 3):

When you access your instance `obj` through the parent-class, **which doesn´t have any knowledge on `y`**, you surely can´t access that member as it´s only defined on the child-class.

In other words: every `Child` is a `Parent` and has an `y`-property. But not every `Parent` is also a `Child`.

Thus your reference `obj` must have the compile-time-type `Child`, not `Parent`:

```
Child obj = new Child();
obj.y = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do.
This is because any instance of ClassB is also an instance of ClassA but vice versa is not true.

Additionally if above statement is not clear, Unless there's a good reason, it is better to avoid the situation where parent class is dependent on child class.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because you are using a variable of type Parent and parent does not expose a property y.

Answer (score 1):

To access members from derived type using a variable of base type, you should explicitly cast the variable to a derived type:

```
Parent parent = new Child();
Child child = (Child) parent;
child.y = 10;
```

But you should keep in mind that `Child child = (Child)parent` can throw a runtime exception if `parent` contains an object of another type. For example, this code throws a runtime exception:

```
Parent parent = new AnotherChild();
Child child = (Child) parent;
```

You can avoid runtime exception by using the `is` operator:

```
if (parent is Child) 
{
    Child child = (Child) parent;
    child.y = 10;
}
```

Or better by using the `as` operator

```
Child child = parent as Child;
if (child != null)
{
    child.y = 10;
}
```

The `as` operator never throws an exception. Instead, if the object can’t be cast, it returns null.